# ASP Textbox value not receiving to VB code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I'm trying to make a send message form using some template. I'm trying to get textbox values to vb code behind and store it to sql but the textbox text is not sending to server side. It is receiving Blank value. So can anyone figure out what is the problem.

- Tried even with receiving to msgbox and still the same.
- Tried with AJAX Updatepanel but still the same.

HTML Code

```
 <section id="message">
            <div class="contact_index">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-8 contact_index-left">
                        <h3>Send Us A Message</h3>
                        <div class="contact-form">

                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" class="textbox" required="required" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" required="required" value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

                               <%-- <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}">
                                <textarea value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message</textarea>--%>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server"><h3>Send Now</h3></asp:LinkButton>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

VB Code

```
Protected Sub LinkButton4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton4.Click
    MsgBox(TextBox2.Text)

End Sub
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: 'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Value)'  there is no input  type="text" value="name"

Comment: @artisdextrus Actually importing to sql is not a problem. Name.value is the value from hidden field. I'm nit getting textbox2 and textbix3 value from html.

Comment: are you setting the value of textbox2 anywhere else?

Comment: No. I'm not setting elsewhere.

Comment: I just test your code and **msgbox** is showing correctly the content of **textbox2**

Comment: I also checked this code and works perfectly but not here. Is there anything to do with div classes? Or any CSS class would interfere this?